# React Native: unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager

Tags: android, react-native

When I try to launch React Native Expo on Android (RN version 0.70.5), I get a white screen:
[image]
And these errors (Physical device & Emulator):

```
02-06 21:52:55.262  3880 10289 D SoLoader: libreactnativejni_abi47_0_0.so found on /data/app/~~FAT6nGOtIVMGO3mGD6W8wQ==/host.exp.exponent-9_PmD5rFSzAj-3A9jagoXw==/lib/x86
02-06 21:52:55.263  3880 10289 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativejni_abi47_0_0.so
02-06 21:52:55.374  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
02-06 21:52:55.376  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
02-06 21:52:55.377  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
02-06 21:52:55.379  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
02-06 21:52:55.380  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
02-06 21:52:55.381  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
02-06 21:52:55.381  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
02-06 21:52:55.382  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
02-06 21:52:55.383  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
02-06 21:52:55.384  3880 10296 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
...
02-06 21:52:55.702  3880 10295 V SoLoader: libreactnativeblob_abi47_0_0.so not found on /data/data/host.exp.exponent/lib-main
02-06 21:52:55.702  3880 10295 D SoLoader: libreactnativeblob_abi47_0_0.so found on /data/app/~~FAT6nGOtIVMGO3mGD6W8wQ==/host.exp.exponent-9_PmD5rFSzAj-3A9jagoXw==/lib/x86
02-06 21:52:55.702  3880 10295 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativeblob_abi47_0_0.so
02-06 21:57:04.746  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:4)
02-06 21:57:04.746  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.modules.deviceinfo.DeviceInfoModule.invalidate(DeviceInfoModule.java:2)
02-06 21:57:04.746  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:2)
02-06 21:57:04.746  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:4)
02-06 21:57:04.746  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
02-06 21:57:04.746  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1)
02-06 21:57:04.746  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:4)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule.invalidate(NativeAnimatedModule.java:1)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:2)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:4)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:4)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule.invalidate(FrescoModule.java:2)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:2)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:4)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1)
02-06 21:57:04.777  3880 10296 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at abi47_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
...
02-06 21:59:20.225 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_codegen_rncore.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.225 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_codegen_rncore_abi45_0_0.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.225 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_codegen_rncore_abi46_0_0.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.225 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_codegen_rncore_abi47_0_0.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.225 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_config.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.225 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_config_abi45_0_0.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.225 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_config_abi46_0_0.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.226 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_config_abi47_0_0.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.226 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_debug.so: deferring to libdir
02-06 21:59:20.226 10982 10982 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreact_debug_abi45_0_0.so: deferring to libdir
...
02-06 21:59:22.599 10982 11169 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.shopify.reactnative.skia.SkiaPictureViewManager
02-06 21:59:22.599 10982 11169 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.shopify.reactnative.flash_list.AutoLayoutViewManager
02-06 21:59:22.600 10982 11169 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.com.shopify.reactnative.flash_list.CellContainerManager
02-06 21:59:22.600 10982 11169 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.expo.modules.adapters.react.views.ViewGroupManagerAdapter
02-06 21:59:22.601 10982 11169 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class abi47_0_0.expo.modules.adapters.react.views.SimpleViewManagerAdapter
02-06 21:59:22.919 10982 11121 V SoLoader: libreactnativeblob.so not found on /data/data/host.exp.exponent/lib-main
02-06 21:59:22.919 10982 11121 D SoLoader: libreactnativeblob.so found on /data/app/~~bwQn5SKKEr0cSj0hPcvbHQ==/host.exp.exponent-64zqlKE3z_s6MbrsjM8nKQ==/lib/x86
02-06 21:59:22.919 10982 11121 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativeblob.so
02-06 21:59:22.989 10982 11168 V SoLoader: libreactnativeblob_abi47_0_0.so not found on /data/data/host.exp.exponent/lib-main
02-06 21:59:22.989 10982 11168 D SoLoader: libreactnativeblob_abi47_0_0.so found on /data/app/~~bwQn5SKKEr0cSj0hPcvbHQ==/host.exp.exponent-64zqlKE3z_s6MbrsjM8nKQ==/lib/x86
02-06 21:59:22.989 10982 11168 D SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativeblob_abi47_0_0.so
```

When I run React Native on Web, it works OK.
What could be the reason behind these errors?

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you tried to clean gradle and run app again?

Comment: @VickyAhuja This is an expo project. I dont have android\Ios folders and I prefer it to stay simple like that